# Will a Brownian Particle hit an infinite wall in 3-D geometry with probability 1?

Tags: diffusion, brownian-motion

I know that in 3-D the probability of recurring a given point is zero for a Brownian particle.

**Given an infinite absorbing wall/plane the probability of ultimately getting absorbed, for a Brownian particle, in 3-D geometry is '1'?**

Comment: Further more the probability of hitting a line should be 0 if I'm not mistaken